# Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask for a review of my github account?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm starting out in computer science and wondering if I should put my github on my resume.  Is there a site I can ask for someone to review it?

Comment: Clearly it belongs on http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: @random not if it is too large though or there are bugs.

Comment: @random clearly you must be joking?  That's for specific *working* code, not "Hey, guys, here's my github, tell me if I'm a sht programmer!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select portions of code *that work* (and that fit within the chararacter limit) can fit on codereview.SE.

Reviewing you entire github account is often (for an average project) a large enough task to require reimbursement and looking for freelancers is off-topic everywhere on the SE Q&A network.